# Display string with whitespace in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, string, whitespace

I need to display a string which has a white space on a asp.net page.

****Here is what I am doing:****

```
cell = New TableCell

cell.Text = value  (lets assume value is <"  test with whitespace    ">

row.Cells.Add(cell)
```

**and it gets rendered as**

```
<tr>
<td>"  test with whitespace    "</td>
</tr>
```

whitespaces within single quotes are not displayed.

I want this value to be displayed as it is on my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML strips out all but one space character. You need to use the &NBSP; entity to ensure white space is presented with HTML. Use the String class's Replace method (or RegEx) to swap out each space for &NBSP;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you try to get a space before and after your text to get some spacing between the border of the table cell and your text?

If so you should have a look at the CSS style "**padding**" or padding-left, padding-right. This will add space between the tables border and your text.

Add this to your page:

```
<style type="text/css">
td {
padding: 4px;
}
</style>
```

If this is not what you are after, I apologize.